# Matematica. Residue integral

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I just started to use Mathematica and wanted to try out if I got a result correct from a residue integral i made. I have two poles in the UHP, actually looking more complicated but I just wanted to see if Mathematica could to this. This is my code:

```
x1 = Iw;
x2 = 2 Iw;

Integrate [e^(Ixt)/((x - x1) (x - x2)), {x, -infinity, infinity}, Assumptions -> t > 0]
```

Is this integral possible to do in Mathematica?

Comment: Why are you asking us when you could more easily have asked Mathematica ?  That might have raised an error message, but no snarky comments.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica sees Iw as a two character variable name, but I w as the product of two things.
Mathematica is fanatic about correct capitalization and spelling.

```
x1=I w; x2=2 I w;
Integrate[E^(I x t)/((x-x1)(x-x2)), {x,-Infinity,Infinity}, Assumptions-> t>0]
```

returns a large complicated result depending on the signs and whether w might be zero. If you can supply additional domain information the result might be simplified.